# MouseOver effect for button in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a `DataTemplate` to show some buttons with a customized view (with an image, text, etc). Here is a simplified example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ActionItem}">

    <Button Background="SlateGray" Command="{Binding Command}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

    </Button>

</DataTemplate>
```

**Why is the mouse over effect not working at all?**

Comment: @S.Akbari: The related answer tells to use a control template, which I already do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Background="SlateGray"` overrides anything you can trigger in a Style. Remove that bit and it should work.

Comment: that should not be the case bcos when the trigger fires it temporary overrides current control style with whatever you set in the trigger

Comment: @Pamparanpa It's not set in the Control Style, the DP is set directly - test it yourself if you don't believe me. Btw: yours doesn't work for the same reason.

Comment: @Manfred: You were right, feeling silly right now... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the trigger at at the template level like

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ActionItem}">

    <Button Background="SlateGray" Command="{Binding Command}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>

                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

            </Style>
        </Button.Style>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

    </Button>

</DataTemplate>
```